# Get level of wellness in a cascade classifier using LBP

Tags: opencv, classification, local-features, c++

I'm currently working in a Lolipop LBP cascade detector using OpenCV. The training is correctly done and the cascade classifier detects the sticks of the Lolipops correctly but with some minor errors.

[image]

Is there any way to obtain a "level of trust" or an index of how many features had been detected during the cascade detection process?